# Current Logged in user can't be found after filtering primary key in django application using REST framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, rest, deployment

After filtering the user objects, I can see the current logged in user in json format when I go to this url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_profile_info/', but when I do 'print(userData)' it prints this empty json '{'user': []}', but it should print the current logged in user in json format.

Logged in user in json format: {'user': [{'id': 1, 'username': 'JerryTaylor13', 'email': 'JerryTaylor13@gmail.com', 'password': 'f49fidaf#', 'settings': {}}]}

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_profile_info(request):

     user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)
     serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
     return JsonResponse({"user": serializer.data}, safe=False)

@login_required
def profile(request):

     response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_profile_info/')
     userData = response.json()
     print(userData)

     return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User #authentication system



class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)  # Hashed password
    settings = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, Subject, Project, Task, FocusSession, Tally, Badge, Streak, Reflection

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

The user models and its fields are shown on the django admin site but not in the tables of my postgresSQL db.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `requests.get` is made from your machine and not from the user, thus is has no user. This is correct. What do you wanna achieve with the `profile` function? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: In the profile method, I'd like to to pass the username field of the current logged in  'User' in the render method, so I can view a profile page with the username of the current logged in user.

Comment: @Marco From my last comment however, I get a key error when use this in the profile method: return render(request, 'profile.html', {
        'username': userData['username']
        
    })

Comment: As said, you will never receive a user because your machine is making the call to the endpoint and not a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response = requests.get('http:...` will never receive a user since the call is not made from a user.
To receive the username in your profile method, just use:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'username': request.user.username
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```